# A condition in C prints only 1 results regardless of input

Tags: c

I'm a little stumped. I have a feeling I've gone wrong somewhere in my code but can't seem to quite put my finger on it. Basically I was assigned to put together a C code which supposedly simulates a police radar gun. A user would insert an integer, and based on input the user would be advised whether that input would be speeding or not, and if it was a specific fine would be given.

Below is my code

```
/* *****

Author: Shivan Kamal
Date: 12-3-2015
Program Reason: To simulate a police speed radar by getting user to insert a number
        and to give them an answer to whether they are speed or not, and provide a warning or a fine
        where required.

*****/

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    /***** 
    Declaring values
    ******/
    int speed;
    const int LIMIT1 = 60;
    const int LIMIT2 = 65;
    const int LIMIT3 = 70;
    const int LIMIT4 = 80;
    const int LIMIT5 = 200;

    const int FINE1 = 80;
    const int FINE2 = 150;
    const int FINE3 = 500;

    /*****
    Beginning of the program
    *****/

    printf(" If you want to check whether a certain speed issues you\n");
    printf(" a warning or a fine and how much, please input a number value\n");
    printf(" NOTE: the number value will be in KM/h.\n");
    scanf("%d%*c" , speed);

    if(speed == 0)
    {
        printf(" Your vehicle is not moving at '0'km/h. If your car was blocking traffic, you would be issued a fine. Please be careful.\n");
    }
    else 
        if(speed <0)
        {
            printf("Your vehicle is most likely in reverse. If this is the case and your vehicle disrupts traffic. You may be issued a fine. Please be careful.\n");
        }
        else
            if(speed <= LIMIT1)
            {
                printf("You're within the speed limit.\n");
            }
            else
                if(speed <= LIMIT2)
                {
                    printf("SPEEDING - Warning! You are going over the speed limit.\n Please slow down or you may be issued a fine");
                }
                else
                    if(speed <= LIMIT3)
                    {
                        printf("SPEEDING - You have gone over the speed limit.\n Fined $FINE1.\n");
                    }
                    else
                        if(speed <= LIMIT4)
                        {
                            printf("SPEEDING - You have gone over the speed limit.\n Fined $FINE2.\n");
                        }
                        else
                            if(speed <= LIMIT5)
                            {
                                printf("SPEEDING - You have gone over the speed limit.\n Fined $FINE3.\n");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                printf(" By getting caught going faster than any limit higher than 20km/h.\n Your fine will simply keep getting bigger.\n");
                                printf("Please stick to the speed limit and follow the rules.\n");
                            }

return(0);
}
```

When compiling the code and running it, regardless of what a user inputs, provides one particular message over and over. The message is in the screenshot.

[image]

Can anyone advise me, where I'm going wrong?

Also exactly how do constant variables get printed in a `printf` statement. That's one other part I think I'm doing wrong as well.

Comment: I'll just leave this here:
http://www.murdoch.edu.au/TNE/Roles-and-Responsibilities/Rights-and-Responsibilities-of-Students/Academic-Integrity/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
scanf("%d%*c" , speed);
```

to

```
scanf("%d%*c" , &speed);
```

You need to use `&` when accepting values with `scanf()`. The unary `&` returns the address of the variable following it. `scanf()` stores the values in that address. So you need to use `&` in `scanf()`. But you don't need to use `&` for `printf()` ( unless you want to print the address of that variable for some reason )

You should also change your 3 `printf()` statements with the fine to

```
printf("SPEEDING - You have gone over the speed limit.\n Fined $%d.\n",FINE1);
printf("SPEEDING - You have gone over the speed limit.\n Fined $%d .\n", FINE2);
printf("SPEEDING - You have gone over the speed limit.\n Fined $%d .\n", FINE3);
```

Otherwise, it won't show the value of the FINE's

Comment: haha such a silly mistake. Can't believe i missed something so small. I got a lot of learning to do. Thanks @Arun A.S .. Also what about printing a constant variable in `printf`?

Comment: @Shivarn , `&` returns the address of the variable right after it and `scanf()` stores the value in that address. But you don't need to use `&` for `printf()`